# Video appears twice in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I have a small problem. My colleagues at work use Windows XP, thus IE 8. So, I have some coding so that people can view it using Chrome and IE 8 and Edge. But, I wanted to try it on IE 9, just in case some poor customer has IE 9 (who knows, it could happen!). I know I shouldn't give a crap about IE 9 (which I really don't), but the reality is that most of our customers are old and probably wouldn't download updates (as they may either not know how or wouldn't bother).

I have this coding, but in IE 9 the video appears twice, but in IE 8, if I add the option specifically targeting IE but not IE 9+, no videos appears in IE 8. If, on the other hand, I remove the lt IE 9 code and the gte IE 9 code, then of course it appears in IE 8.

I have been looking for a few hours to fix my problem but to no avail. My question is, how can I modify my code so I can view it in IE 8, IE 9, IE edge and Chrome correctly? (Btw, I had to add the comment-like code in order for this code to work correctly, or else the code appears as text)

```
<!--[if IE & (lt IE 9)]>

<object width="408" height="230"  type="video/x-ms-asf" url="videos/town-and-country.mp4" data="videos/town-and-country.mp4" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
  <param name="url" value="videos/town-and-country.mp4">
  <param name="filename" value="videos/town-and-country.mp4">
  <param name="autostart" value="0">
  <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
  <param name="autosize" value="1">
  <param name="playcount" value="1"> 
  <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="videos/town-and-country.mp4" width="408" height="230"    autostart="false" showcontrols="true" 

pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>

<![endif]-->


<!--<![if !IE | (gte IE 9)]>-->
<video id="" src="videos/town-and-country.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls width="408" height="230"></video>
<!--<![endif]>-->
```

EDIT, these are the mods I have for now:

```
<video src="videos/town-and-country.mp4" width="408" height="230" controls>
  <source src="videos/town-and-country.webm" type="video/webm">


<object width="408" height="230"  type="video/x-ms-asf" url="videos/town-and-country.mp4" data="videos/town-and-country.mp4" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
  <param name="url" value="videos/town-and-country.mp4">
  <param name="filename" value="videos/town-and-country.mp4">
  <param name="autostart" value="0">
  <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
  <param name="autosize" value="1">
  <param name="playcount" value="1"> 
  <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="videos/town-and-country.mp4" width="408" height="230"    autostart="false" showcontrols="true" 

pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the conditional comments. Try putting the object *inside* the `video` tag.

- IE versions less than 9 will ignore the `video` tag and will render the Windows Media Player object by default.
- Modern browsers (and IE9+) will ignore the child object and play the native video.

Like this:

```
<video src="videos/town-and-country.mp4">
   <object>
    // Your fallback WMP object here
   </object>
</video>
```

As a word of caution, though - I don't think Windows Media Player on XP supports playing mp4 files. [According to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316992), only Windows Media Player 12 supports that - and WMP 12 [only works with Windows 7+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player). Also, you will need to add a webm version of your video for other browsers that can't play mp4.

Comment: I modified it to try to add a second vid extension. But with IE9, it still adds that video. You can check out the added EDIT I placed in the OP. (the MP4 works with XP btw, I tried it out).

Comment: Put the mp4 in a <source> element too - otherwise the src attribute will take precedence. I'm not sure what problem you are having now. Maybe you could mock up some working code in jsbin?

Comment: It literally duplicates my video, and thus I have two in the end. This happens only in IE9 (not IE8 or 11, nor Chrome). I have never used jsbin before. I am doing this wrong it seems? I can't figure out for the life of me what I am doing wrong on it lol. But here it is nonetheless. http://jsbin.com/woyah/2/

Comment: Are you testing in IE 9 (real) or in IE 11 using the emulation mode? I made a few changes to your sample, but your site is down for maintenance now and I can't test the video. http://jsbin.com/woyah/4

Comment: I think I know why you couldn't view them. The server is up, but I just finally realized after a few hours that the url isn't the same as the one on the server. At the moment, there are some problems with how we set up the server AND the other server that hosts us. A bit complicated. But on my end, it obviously does work in terms of the correct url.

Right now nothing's loading fully except in IE11, go figure why IE loads. When we get that up & running correctly, I'll definitely give you an update about the jsbin that you modified. Maybe the traffic on the website is too heavy for some reason.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that I run the emulated version of IE9 in IE11.

Comment: The links to the videos are still broken. Did you figure out what is wrong? If you are testing this code locally through IE 11 (emulated 9), you might be having issues with IE's compat mode. Try adding the following meta tag to the head of your page: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: Hi Tim. Sorry for the late response. I was sick last week. Yes, the problem was that the original URL (long ago) was not the same as it is today. HOWEVER, they still use the same url. So locally with the proper access, it works fine. But, while trying to manipulate it from another website (as in jsbin), it is trying to take a video from a url that does not exist anymore. I don't know if I am explaining correctly lol. In any case, we have not had any complaints about the videos so far :)

Comment: Alos, I think that the emulation doesn't properly read the code. It's impossible for me to tell, as I do not have IE9. But, I am sure that the code you provided works perfectly even in IE9. If IE8 reads it, why wouldn't IE9? I have XP on my laptop and 7 on my desktop. So, I think the emulation is misreading something. Which wouldn't be the first time. Not for me anyhow. I have IE8 and IE11, hence why I am highly skeptical about the emulation in this case.

Random question, is it possible to emulate edge on a lower version? Say IE9 or IE10?